# How to Drop Output Field

Tags: hive, hiveql

Problem:
My `SELECT` statement results with two outputs, but the requirement is for **ONLY** ID:

My current Hive QL output:
ID  player.weight

```
My current Hive Query:<br></br>
    SELECT DISTINCT b.id ,m.weight as weight 
    FROM batting b  
    JOIN 
    Master m on (m.id = b.id)
    WHERE b.year = 2005 AND  b.triples >4 
    ORDER BY weight DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Is there a way to save my results, and then query the first ID column? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I needed to wrap the whole thing as a subquery, then just select the id.